# How to add an array of key value pairs to a Map in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

I have an array of key value pairs where each key has an another array of constant length (i.e., 2) as the value. How can I add the entire array to a `Map()` without just doing `Map.set(key, value)` for every pair?

I know that while creating a `Map()` instance I could pass an iterable like an array to it ex: `let x = new Map(arr);` But this is not supported in IE 11 as per the documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#Browser_compatibility). So, could anyone help me out with an alternate implementation.

At the end of the day, I just want to be able to access the two values with a string key. If there is an another way I could implement, please guide me.

Here is the example:

I created a key value mapping array as follows:

```
let arr = [
        ['ar', ['cl', 'bl']],
        ['bs', ['kl', 'ml']],
        ['cs', ['rk', 'uk']],
        ['da', ['mk', 'ak']]
    ];
let map = new Map(arr); // This isn't working.
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to support browsers where the `Map` is not implemented, just use ordinary object, where the 1st array item will be keys & 2nd (the sub-array) values:

```
var arr = [
        ['ar', ['cl', 'bl']],
        ['bs', ['kl', 'ml']],
        ['cs', ['rk', 'uk']],
        ['da', ['mk', 'ak']]
    ];

var map = arr.reduce(function (obj, item) {
    obj[item[0]] = item[1];
    return obj;
}, {});

console.log(map['ar'], map.bs);
```

Or ES2015 approach (won't work in IE11):

```
const map = arr.reduce((obj, item) => ({
    ...obj,
    [item[0]]: item[1],
}), {});
```

If you want to access the subarray by the string key, you'd have to convert it from array anyways.

If you'd want to use `Map`, then (apart from fixing typos in your array definition) you'll extract the contents by Map.prototype.get function:

```
var map = new Map(arr);
console.log(map.get('bs'));
```

If you don't want to create a new object, another approach could be using Array.filter:

```
arr.filter(function (item) { return item[0] === 'ar' })[0][1];
arr.filter((item) => item[0] === 'ar')[0][1]; // ES2015
```

(potentially wrapped in a function)

Comment: If I don't have the key in the object. How could I handle that situation?

Comment: Not sure what do you mean, like having just the subarray `['cl', 'bl']` instead of `['ar', ['cl', 'bl']]`? Then keep it an ordinary array, from which you can select by index, or you can convert it to an object e.g. by making  the 1st item a key like `{ cl: ['cl', 'bl'], kl: ['kl', 'ml'] }`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a object

```
let obj = 
{ ar:['cl', 'bl'],
  bs:['kl', 'ml'],
  cs:['rk', 'uk'],
  da:['mk', 'ak']
};
console.log(obj['bs'][1]); // displays 'ml'
```